# I can not see my devices with libusb

Tags: c++, usb, libusb

When i run the following code:

```
#include "usb.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    usb_init();
    printf("usb_find_busses: %d\n", usb_find_busses());
    printf("usb_find_devices: %d\n", usb_find_devices());
}
```

It returns:

```
usb_find_busses: 1
usb_find_devices: 0
```

With usb-view.exe i can see my devices. Why cant libsub not see my devices?